# Laravel Application: What comes first

Tags: laravel

For me its always a headache that from where to start coding a laravel  application.

Like first set all the the `views` and `routes` then make all the `controller` according to the plan, Then make `models` and `migrations`, Then have the relationships.

- What things comes first ?

Comment: I suggest you to start here https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals you need to understand MVC concept, answering your question the way it is won't be very helpful if you do not dig in MVC and laravel fundamentals.

Comment: I have completed that series weeks ago.
What i am talking about is that what are the initial steps that should be taken when we starts a project.

Comment: I have not thing to say, if that is the case. good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an incremental coding and if you don't have any TDD in mind, :

I would first start with individual routes and then create the controller methods. At this time, I would write any migrations and make models for it. Once this is set, I can then create views and make a complete workflow.

But if you are following a **TDD**, I would first make the unit tests and then try to make the tests pass. This would enable you to create the migrations and models first. Unit tests wouldnt touch the controller methods but only the model and database. Once you pass the unit tests, write the controller methods and then the views. Now you can write the integration test for this code.